how does node js and an html form send and recieve data
I need help to understand where the data is stored and sent from node js and how an html form sends data. My plan is to save form data as a txt file on my pc
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors()); // Allows request from any IP (prevent any CORS error)

// Enable parsing of URL-encoded data on all routes:
app.use(express.urlencoded({
   extended: false, // Whether to use algorithm that can handle non-flat data strutures
   limit: 10000, // Limit payload size in bytes
   parameterLimit: 2, // Limit number of form items on payload
}));


app.post('what do i put in here', function(req, res) {

   console.log(req.body);
   // { firstName: 'Barry', lastName: 'Manilow' }

});

app.listen(3000);

Where is the data from the html form so I can check it? I get cannot post.
I got this code from: https://openjavascript.info/2023/03/13/receive-form-data-in-node-js-with-and-without-files/

The HTML is actually missing here. You usually return your HTML from a get call and then you have a post call where you handle the posted data from the client.

so the get call would be here app.post("............', function(req, res)  in the node js and the post would be in the client side

Nope, app.get and app.post are at the server side. The app.get returns a page that is rendered at the client side in the browser. Let me know if you need an example.
